# How to define behave during serialization an object to attribute in XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have some problem with serialization an object to XML. At the beggining, this is class Order which have some properties of types like string, int...

```
public class Order
{
    [XmlAttribute("ObjectType")]
    public string TypeName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("TID")]
    public string TID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("Command")]
    public Command Command
    {
        get; set; 
    }

    public Order()
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see, this class has also one property of type Command. Command class has one string property called Name:

```
public class Command
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

What's the problem? I need to get result like this:

```
<Order ObjectType="TestCase" ID="2" TID="W404" Command="SomeCommand" />
```

Where 'SomeCommand' is value of 'Name' property of this Command object.

With simple words: i need to define behave of how Command object should be serialized to XML attribute - return Name string. Very important thing is that also I have to be able to deserialize this XML to objects structure.

Hope my post is understandable and my problem is explained clearly. ;)

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some way to reconstruct the command from the command name, you can introduce a derived property `CommandName` to serialize the name, and use [xml serialization attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make [`XmlSerializer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/XmlSerializer) output the desired properties as attributes with the desired names:

```
public class Order
{
    [XmlAttribute("ObjectType")]
    public string TypeName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("TID")]
    public string TID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Command Command
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("Command")]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string CommandName
    {
        get
        {
            return Command == null ? null : Command.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            // Logic to convert CommandName to Command, e.g.:
            Command = Command.FindByName(value); // or whatever.
        }
    }

    public Order()
    {
    }
}
```

The `CommandName` property must be public in order for this to work.